# Adding shadow on all four sides of an UIImage iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, shadow

I am trying to add a shadow to all four sides of a imageView.  I see that:
    self.shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 20); put a shadow on two sides.
How do I put a shadow on all four sides?

Comment: Have you tried setting the shadowRadius?

Answer (score 20):

Just set `shadowOffset` to (0,0) or something close.  Adjust `shadowRadius` if you want the shadow to be bigger.  The default is 3 but you may have to increase it.  You also may want to play with `shadowOpacity` to determine the visibility of the shadow.

Comment: This did it:self.sampleTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
    self.shadowView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
    CALayer *layer = shadowView.layer;
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
    layer.shadowRadius = 15;

Answer (score 3):

```
_yourImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
```

This line plays the game. Try increasing your `shadowRadius`. Thus you will get the shadow on all 4 sides.