# Unable to apply Shadow on all the sides of collectionView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, shadow

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to make drop shadow of all the sides but it is just applicable on Bottom and right side. Any idea what i am missing?
This is my code

```
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.5f, 2.5f);
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Comment: It's because you set the `shadowOffset`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038559/uibutton-shadow-on-all-4-sides

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIButton shadow on all 4 sides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038559/uibutton-shadow-on-all-4-sides)

Comment: place the uiview on collection view cell then give shadow to that view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding shadow on all four sides of an UIImage iOS 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915429/adding-shadow-on-all-four-sides-of-an-uiimage-ios-6-0)

Comment: set your `UICollectionView` `clipsToBounds` to `NO`.

Comment: Don't do this, this will make a big performance issue, avoid shadow in cells, instead I suggest to use shadow image.I have bad experience with this.
In old iPads it was causing scrolling issues.

Comment: @ZaidPathan if he draws shadow to a `UIView` inside the cell and then the cells are re-used, there won't be a performance issue?

Comment: @Rikh That's what I thought earlier but in current iPhones it maybe working well, but in iPad 2 or iPod touch 4 it would be a performance issue as I already have experience of that.

Comment: @ZaidPathan Performance can be fixed by setting the layer's `shadowPath`

Comment: @AshleyMills ok I think I need to explore in this direction then.

Answer (score 2):

The shadows extend beyond the bounds of the collection view, so are being clipped *by* the collection view.

You can fix this by setting a `sectionInset` wider than the `shadowRadius` (so there's a gap between the cells and the containing collection view), or by setting `collectionView.clipsToBounds = false`